# Should I use a large random value for i in BIP 32 instead of sequential?

Tags: wallet, cryptography, bip32-hd-wallets

BIP32 doesn't have any guidance on how to choose the i value for child keys.

Is there any benefit to using a random value for i ?

Other than documenting and saving the value of I for various purposes such as auditing and child keys, is there any reason that it should be sequential, or why it shouldn't be a large random number ?

Answer (score 2):

Sequential has the advantage of being able to recover without scanning for 2^32 keys.